# AWS Kaa Sandox Connection timed out from Application

Tags: kaa

I am always getting the connetion timed out error, when running application for AWS Sandbox for Kaa 0.10.0:

*`Failed to receive operation servers list {}
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to ec2-52-201-214-219.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9889 [ec2-52-201-214-219.compute-1.amazonaws.com/52.201.214.219] failed: Connection timed out: connect`*

I noticed that the conenction request is always made to **ec2-52-201-214-219.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9889** irrespective of my AWS Sandbox Public DNS.

I watched the [Introducing Kaa IoT platform Sandbox 0.7.0](https://youtu.be/ynbxcRdgXFU) avilable on the Kaa Project Getting Started Page. The video talked about the Oracle VB, but it did ask to update the IP address of the application so that Kaa server can talk globally. I never got that option in the AWS Sanbox.

I tried a few things to see if this fixes the issue:

1. Open the AWS Sanbox wide open on internet i.e. allowing 0.0.0.0/0 on incoming all incoming. I made sure AWS security group as well as Sanbox firewall both allowed this.
2. Launch new AWS Sanbox
3. Build the application from source

None of these steps worked for me. My AMI details are:

**`Kaa-sandbox-0.10.0 (ami-xxxxxx5d)`**
  `Description: Kaa Sandbox version 0.10.0`
  `Status: available`
  `Platform: Other Linux`
  `Image Size: 30GB`
  `Visibility: Public`
  `Owner: xxxxxxxx2249`

Here is my [kaa-desktop-client.log](http://pastebin.com/1WEXpG4A) file. I was using MobaXterm on Win10 for runing the

I haven't tried the Oracle VB method yet, but will post the updates soon.

Could you please help me identify the problem? Or this is a bug? I think the HTTP connection should be to `<my AWS Kaa Public DNS>:9899` instead of `ec2-52-201-214-219.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9889` all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found **a solution** to this issue after back-tracing in to the server. I followed these steps:

1. Change `gui_change_host_enabled=false` to **`true`** under `/usr/lib/kaa-sanbox/conf/sandbox-server.properties`
2. Restart the Sandbox process `sudo service kaa-sandbox restart` (Kaa AWS Sandbox is an Ubuntu machine)
3. Visit `http://<AWS Kaa Public Domain>:9080/sandbox`
4. `Management Tab` should show up now. (You should also expect a pop up to change the host... there is a parameter in the same conf that's enabled by default.)
5. Update the `Host` with `<Your AWS Kaa Instance Public DNS>`. It will take a moment to clean up the cache
6. Change `gui_change_host_enabled=true` back to **`false`** under `/usr/lib/kaa-sanbox/conf/sandbox-server.properties` same as original conf
7. Download the binary or source for your sandbox applications again, and you should not get the Connection Timeout problem

Ultimately this updates the `transport_public_interface=<Your AWS Kaa Instance Public DNS>` parameter in `/usr/lib/kaa-node/conf/kaa-node.properties` and clears the cache of Sandbox downloaded apps.

This was not documented on the website, so I would suggest to update the documentation for AWS Kaa Sanbox. I understand that the Management